# Criar evento para verificar duração de exibição de imagens, semelhante ao video no HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

Galera, tava dando uma olhada na tag [video](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) do html5 e vi que essa tem bastante eventos de controle, como [esse](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_timeupdate.asp), assim sendo possível saber quando um vídeo esta preste a acabar e também disparar um evento quando esse acabar.

Gostaria de saber se existe algo semelhante para imagem, por exemplo, se eu quisesse fazer um player de imagem e vídeo, como eu saberia que uma imagem que tem que tocar X tempo esta preste a acabar sem ter que ter um **setInterval** verificando o tempo atual e o tempo da imagem pra saber se ela já terminou ou não.

Alguém já fez algo parecido? Alguma dica?

Comment: Player de imagem?

Comment: É, é só um exemplo

Comment: Você quer saber quando ela termina de ser carregada ?

Comment: No título tá meio que "nada a ver" com a pergunta.

Comment: Não, por exemplo, um vídeo tem duração de 10s. Com a tag video, eu consigo disparar um evento (acredito que sim) quando o vídeo termine de rodar. E se eu quiser que uma imagem também rode durante 10s, tem como eu criar eventos pra isso?

Comment: Sim, você pode fazer evento enquanto tiver rodando aparece a imagem e quanto evento do video tiver terminado você esconde a imagem

Comment: pode tentar usar o `setTimeout()`